# Distribute horizontal padding for each button in a horizontal menu

Tags: css, flexbox

I try to code a CSS menu with this conditions:

- No javascript
- No width specified on items
- First item sticked to left
- Last item sticked to right
- No space between items
- Same space between words (same padding for each item)

Result expected: http://hpics.li/38b0720

Here is the html:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Breadfruit</li>
    <li>Bilberry</li>
    <li>Blackberry</li>
    <li>Blackcurrant</li>
    <li>Blueberry</li>
    <li>Boysenberry</li>
    <li>Cantaloupe</li>
    <li>Currant</li>
    <li>Cherry</li>
</ul>
```

And here is the basic css:

```
#menu{width:960px;background:#ccc;}
#menu li{padding:10px 0;text-align:center;background:#000;}
```

What I tried :

- "float:left" and specified width on "li": it works, but it's not flexbile. If the word size changes, the style is broken.
- "display:inline-block;padding:10px;" on "li" and "text-align:center" on "ul": the first item isn't sticked to left and the last item isn't sticked to right.
- "display:flex;justify-content:space-between;" on "ul" : there is space between items.
- "display:flex;" on "ul" and "flex:1" on "li" : there isn't the same space between words.
- "display:table;" on "ul" and "display:table-cell" on "li" : there isn't the same space between words.

Do you have an idea to do that please? I don't even know if it's possible :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is impossible, with all your arbitrary conditions like "no width specified on items." It may be helpful to provide the code you have already tried... and why you want these conditions... instead of giving us some specification and saying "write my code for me."

Comment: Almost certainly not going to be possible without JS

Comment: It is possible so easy but what you have tried ?

Comment: I just edit my first post. Thank you if you can help me :)

Comment: @Doorknob of Snow : if it's impossible or if you don't know how to do that, just tell me. If it's easy, please show me how to do this. But don't tell me "your question sucks, newbie".

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Now that you have edited the question and showed some effort I am glad to help you.</sub>

If you don't need to support IE7 or lower you can use `display:table-cell` like this:

```
 #menu li {
  display:table-cell;
  width:1%;
 }
```

Check this **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A999r/)**

Comment: "width:1%", this is what I was missing! Thank you very much  Danko.

Comment: @user2724584 Np mate glad to help you. Now you know how to make a question here we are here to help and learn of other. PD . If this was usefull mark this as the answer.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on IE8/IE9, even the Fiddle given as an example. Space between the words isn't the same. Do you have any idea to fix this problem please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Works fine for me in IE8 and IE9 check your document mode in IE maybe has IE7 standards @user2724584

Comment: Here a screenshot with your Fiddle, on IE9. For example, space between "Blackberry" and "Blackcurrant" isn't the same as that between "Currant" and "Cherry" :)
[link](http://hpics.li/53a26a5)

Comment: @user2724584 can I Know why you uncheck the answer? This is the best you can achieve just with CSS and all your conditions.

Answer (score 2):

achievable with flexbox, maybe using display:table as fallback

the same `flex-basis:10px;` applied to all elements does the trick

[image: showing spacing]

**DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/T2G6F/

```
#menu
{
    background:#ccc;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}

#menu li
{
    text-align:center;
    background:#000;
    color:white;
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:8px 10px;
    border:1px red solid;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    flex-basis:10px;
    flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try working with display: table and display:table-cell.

```
<style>

    #menu
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        display: table;
        background-color: black;
    }

    .menu-item
    {
        display: table-cell;
        color: white;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
    }

</style>
```

Something like this.

```
<div id="menu">
        <div class="menu-item">Item 1</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Item 2</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Item 3</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Item 4</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Item 5</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Item 6</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Item 7</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Item 8</div>
    </div>
```

Pay attention that you probably won't be able to set the exactly same space between words. But centering the text and letting the menu-item without defined width might get you close to what you want.

Comment: The downrank was harsh, so I've +1'ed you to even it up, though it's best not to dignify these sort of questions with a response :)

Comment: No no, I tried many things but I failed. It's a true question, thank you LcSalazar for your answer, I don't thank others.